# How to set flags in GWT request payload?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I am trying to implement GWT built-in Xsrf protection.

["GWT Xsrf protection"](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html)

However, when GWT decodes request it checks:

```
RpcToken rpcToken = null;
  if (streamReader.hasFlags(AbstractSerializationStream.FLAG_RPC_TOKEN_INCLUDED)) {
    // Read the RPC token
    rpcToken = (RpcToken) streamReader.deserializeValue(RpcToken.class);
  }
```

The value of flags is present in payload in the second argument which comes to be 0,

7|0|7|http://localhost:8888/app/application_ui/|861077CBD5F6492CF7DAF586B429F9D2|com.drishti.ameyo.common.ui.rpc.CommonGwtRpcService|getInactivityTimeoutForCC|java.lang.String/2004016611|java.lang.Integer/3438268394|d908-5a1d64b9-ses-Administrator-wByUOLdq-0|1|2|3|4|2|5|6|7|6|1|

While FLAG_RPC_TOKEN_INCLUDED is 2, so basically, I need to set flags value=2 in the payload, to deserealize value of RPC token.